# How to translate angular validation message to multi language?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

MyName is a keyvalue and i want to translate it to multilanguage.  If i write translate MyName it works fine. It check for 'MyName' key in database and translate it value to selected language English or Arabic.
Even  if i write MyName inside label atrribute with transalte it works fine.

But my problem is, i want to translate error message to selected language

input type="text" ng-model="Resource.Name" name="Name" required="required" class="form-control text" validationMessage="Name is required" maxlength="20" /

How can i do this?

Comment: https://angular-translate.github.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use these 2 ways in my app which is completely covered by 2 languages

```
1.
<ion-view title="{{ 'LANGUAGE_OPTIONS' | translate }}">

2.
<span translate>{{ 'FORGOT_PASSWORD' }}</span>
```

so in your case it might look something like this

```
validationMessage="{{ 'MESSAGE' | translate }}"
```

and in your language.json

```
"MESSAGE": "Some text"
```

Comment: are you using [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) ? is your syntax exactly the same including " " and ' ' ?

Comment: can you post the code? the block < /> where you try to translate and related json data?

Comment: app.run(function ($rootScope, $cookies, $translate) {
        $rootScope.Init = function () {
            var lang = $cookies.get('_APPLICATION_LANGUAGE') || 'en';           
            $rootScope.setLanguage(lang, $cookies.get('_APPLICATION_LANGUAGECode')||"English");
        };
        $rootScope.setLanguage = function (lang,code) {
            $(".lang").html(code);
            $cookies.put("_APPLICATION_LANGUAGE", lang);
            $cookies.put("_APPLICATION_LANGUAGECode", code);        
            $translate.use(lang);
        }
        $rootScope.Init();
    });

Comment: public object Translate(string lang)
        {
            if (lang == "en")
            {
                return _localStringService.GetResourceByLanguageId(1);
            }
            else
            {
                return _localStringService.GetResourceByLanguageId(2);
            }   
        }

Comment: public object GetResourceByLanguageId(int languageId)
        {
            var resourceObject = new JObject();

            var resourceSet = __localeStringRepository.TableNoTracking.Where(l => l.LanguageId == languageId).ToDictionary(t=>t.Name,t=>t.Value);

            IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = resourceSet.GetEnumerator();

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                resourceObject.Add(enumerator.Key.ToString(), enumerator.Value.ToString());
            }
            return (resourceObject);
        }

Comment: ok this is some js logic behind, that's cool, but you need to do the translation in your html file. also you might want to use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)

Comment: Its working.   How can i translate alert message? Any idea?

Comment: i want to translate message which is inside alert.   Eg: alert("HelloWorld"); Here HelloWorld is a key and i want to translate it to multi language.  How can i do this?

Comment: alert($translate.instant('HelloWorld')); ... and you must inject $translate